# Sequelize, does setting timestamps:true create the createdAt updatedAt columns in the migrations?

Tags: sequelize.js

My migration script in sequelize is not creating the timestamp columns createdAt, updatedAt

`Error: SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'createdAt' in 'field list'`

I thought that setting timestamps to true in the migration definition auto-created the columns, am I wrong?

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('User', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      uname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
      }

    },{
      timestamps: true
    })
...
```

Comment: The [example in the docs](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/migrations/#createtabletablename-attributes-options) manually specifies the timestamps, so I guess you are wrong.

Comment: then I wonder what the purpose of setting the timestamps flag would be?

Comment: Where have you seen that? The model definition and migration system seem to be rather separate. I've only seen the timestamps flag in model definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the migrations and models specifications are different - so don't assume what you do in one, you can do in the other. In models, you often specify some setting and automatic things happen - while in migrations, you seem to have to manually set what was automatic in the models.

So, when you do a `.sync()` on a model, you don't need to specify the columns `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `id` (assuming you've chosen the right options to include timestamps and haven't specified your own primary key) - but a migration requires them to be explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

I am late but for the sake of clarity i will answer. I think you misread what it was talking about.

Timestamps flag is specified in the **Configuration** section of the model definition page and that, altogether with paranoid, underscored, freezetablename, tablename and version flags *"influence the way Sequelize handles your column names"* and in some cases a behavior. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration

Whereas under the section **Timestamps** of the same model definiton page there is the next note:

> If you are using Sequelize migrations you will need to add
>   the createdAt and updatedAt fields to your migration definition:

And it specifies manually adding the timestamps fields to the migration

```
module.exports = {
  up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('my-table', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },

      // Timestamps
      createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
      updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    })
  },
  down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('my-table');
  },
}
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#timestamps